# ASP.NET table to use Bootstrap table css

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently using ASP.NET table because I need to generate rows dynamically at code-behind. When I tried to give my ASP.NET table `Cssclass="table .table-bordered" it doesn't work, may I know why? I really want to use the Css from Bootstrap.

Here's what I have tried

```
<asp:Table ID="myTable" runat="server" Width="70%" HorizontalAlign="Center" CssClass="table table-bordered>
        <asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableCell>#</asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell>Date & Time</asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell>User</asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>
```

Comment: It should work. Are you sure bootstrap is loading? Check with the browser's dev tools. Do a hard refresh of the page (Ctrl+F5 / Cmd+F5).

Comment: Press `F12` => `Console` tab and check if any CSS/JS errors logged there. The Bootstrap CSS classes should work if both CSS & JS files are properly included.